# What does the phrase « que j’étais » add to the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: sens

> Je n’ai fait que la soupçonner, pétri de préjugés ***que j’étais***...
>
> {compared to}: Je n’ai fait que la soupçonner, pétri de préjugés...

I can't seem to pinpoint the difference in meaning between the two versions. A few other examples with a similar sentence construction would also be appreciated  to help it sink in.

Comment: IMHO in the second sentence, as it stands so far (unfinished?) we don't know who is pétri de préjugés, could hesitate when written, but we don't hear the adjectives possible agreement in oral speech. Starting the sentence with *pétri de préjugés* would  in a way resolve the ambiguity, *je* being closer to the apposition. But I'd leave *que je suis / que j'étais* even then (personal opinion).

Comment: @Laure « Je n’ai fait que la soupçonner, **(tout) en étant** pétri de préjugés... » Qu'en penses-tu, d'ailleurs ?

Comment: Ta proposition lève toute ambiguïté, mais elle est moins élégante, et sans doute plus adapté à l'oral qu'à l'écrit.

Comment: « Comme je suis pétri de préjugés » ?

Comment: @LukeSawczak Hi. It seems to me that the use of "comme" does not quite match what the original sentence suggests. In the original, "soupçonner" and "pétri" are *simultaneous*, whereas in the "comme" version, it could be construed as "pétri" in the "comme" clause being followed by "soupçonner". A cause and its result, if you will. What's your take? ;)

Comment: I read it as an explanation, a [reasoning](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/20208/comment-d-autant-que-a-t-il-gliss%C3%A9-s%C3%A9mantiquement-pour-introduire-une-id%C3%A9e-d/25371#25371), rather than the result of a cause (as two separate events). I suspected her, for the reason that / since / being that I'm a pétri de préjugés.

Answer (score 3):

*An English answer follows for learners.*

---

Comme Laure l'a dit, ajouter « que j'étais » résout le problème du « [dangling modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier) » : le syntagme « pétri de préjugés » est clairement en apposition, mais de quel autre syntagme ? Qui est ce pétri ?

Le message à transmettre est plus ou moins clair dans la mesure où l'acte de soupçonner qualifierait n'importe quel contenant de préjugés, mais la syntaxe mine cette interprétation. C'est normalement le groupe nominal le plus proche à l'apposition que qualifie cette dernière. On y entendrait que « la » référerait à une entité quelconque qui est ce pétri. Le contexte minimiserait peut-être la probabilité de ce malentendu mais il reste toujours valide du point de vue grammatical.

« Que j'étais » sert donc à désambiguïser.

Comme l'a noté Laure, rapprocher l'apposition et le GN-cible souhaité rend plus facile la bonne interprétation du point de vue syntaxique :

> Pétri de préjuges, je n'ai fait que la soupçonner.

Mais en français et en anglais, cette construction est jugée maladroite, ne serait-ce que pour la confusion qu'elle est encline à produire.

> Acteur sans talent, j'ai trouvé son interprétation plutôt épuisante.

Par conséquent on ajoutera un peu pour la clarifier, et cela *même dans les cas où malentendre serait impossible*. Voici un mot d'excuse authentique (orthographe légèrement révisée) :

> « Vous avez traité hier mon gars le deuxième de tous les noms. S'il vous manque j'aime autant que vous le frappiez. Parce que ça il le comprendra. Tandis que les gros mots il les comprend pas et maintenant il les répète à tout le monde, comme un con **qu'il est**. Merci. »
>   
> <sub>(Emprunté au recueil de Pierre Ferran et publié dans *Le Monde* le 26 septembre 1977, recueilli [ici](https://www.samuelhuet.com/fr/linguistique/51-scriptur/856-scriptur-excusez-les-parents.html) également.)</sub>

On retrouve toutefois que ce type de construction s'emploie très souvent lors de la conversation spontanée (au moins en anglais ; les francophones devront vérifier pour les milieux français). Il faut remarquer qu'à l'oral il est plus facile de modifier son intonation pour donner l'effet désiré, comme je tenterai de réproduire à l'écrit en soulignant la qualité d'épithète qu'a ce terme dont on se traite  ... :

> Pétri de préjugés ! —  je n'ai fait que la soupçonner.

---

*English for learners.*

As Laure said, adding "que j'étais" resolves the problem of the [dangling modifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dangling_modifier): the unit "pétri de préjugés" is clearly in apposition, but to what other unit? Who is this petri dish?

The message is more or less clear insofar as the act of suspecting would qualify no matter what container of prejudices, but the syntax undermines this reading. It's normally the noun phrase closest to the apposition that the latter qualifies. We would gather that "la" refers to some entity that is the petri dish. The context might minimize the probability of this misreading, but it remains valid from a grammatical point of view.

"Que j'étais" thus serves to disambiguate.

As Laure noted, bringing the apposition closer to the intended target NP makes the correct reading easier from a syntactic point of view:

> Pétri de préjugés, je n'ai fait que la soupçonner.

But in French and English, this construction is deemed awkward, if only for the confusion it tends to produce.

> A talentless actor, I found his performance rather exhausting.

Hence one adds a little to clarify it, *even in cases where the misreading is impossible*. Here's an authentic parental note to explain a child's absence:

> Yesterday you called my boy a bunch of names for the second time. If he disobeys you I'd rather you hit him. Because that he understands. Whereas four-letter words he doesn't understand and now he repeats them to everyone like the moron **he is**.
>   
> <sub>(Taken from the collection of Pierre Ferran and published in *Le Monde*
>    on September 26, 1977, also collected [here](https://www.samuelhuet.com/fr/linguistique/51-scriptur/856-scriptur-excusez-les-parents.html))</sub>

That said, one often finds this kind of construction used in spontaneous conversation (at least in English; the Francophones will have to confirm for French environments). It's worth noting that in spoken dialogue it's easier to modify your intonation to produce the desired effect, which I'll try to reproduce in writing by highlighting that this name the speaker calls himself is an epithet:

> Pétri de préjugés ! — je n'ai fait que la soupçonner.

Comment: Je me disais : « Même sans "que j’étais", de qui pourrait-on parler, sinon de "je" ?! ». Haha. Je ne m’attendais pas à ce que "la" se montre aussi problématique !